# BBEdit find pattern and remove entire table

Tags: html, bbedit

I am by no means an expert and only got BBEdit for a one time project recently.

I am working on a HTML file that has lots of entries I would like to remove. The code I wish to remove are all the tables that  have the string NOT CONVERTED inside them without removing all other tables that  have pretty much the same table pattern but different  text or strings  inside the  table.

```html
<table border=0 width="100%">
<tr>
   <td class="out" valign=top nowrap  width=5%>30.12.2004
      22:34:03&nbsp;<font color=black><b>&gt;</b>TOM&nbsp;&nbsp;</font>
   </td>
   <td class="out"
      align=left>{{{NOT CONVERTED}}}</td>
</tr>
</table

<table border=0 width="100%"><tr><td class="timedel" valign=top nowrap
width=5%>30.12.2004 22:36:37&nbsp;<font
color=black><b>&lt;</b>Benjamin&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></td><td class="incom"  align=left>random string</td></tr></table>

<table border=0 width="100%"><tr><td class="incom" valign=top nowrap  width=5%>30.12.2004
22:36:47&nbsp;<font color=black><b>&lt;</b>Benjamin&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></td><td
class="incom"  align=left>{{{NOT CONVERTED}}}</td></tr></table>

<table border=0 width="100%"><tr><td class="timedel" valign=top nowrap
width=5%>30.12.2004 22:36:47&nbsp;<font
color=black><b>&lt;</b>Benjamin&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></td><td class="incom"  align=left>random chat text</td></tr></table>

<table border=0 width="100%"><tr><td class="incom" valign=top nowrap  width=5%>30.12.2004
22:36:50&nbsp;<font color=black><b>&lt;</b>Benjamin&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></td><td
class="incom"  align=left>{{{NOT CONVERTED}}}</td></tr></table>
```

I have 3000 of those tables in my html file and I wish to find and remove those tables. 
The DATE, NAME and " >" are variables that differ in each table, the rest always has the same pattern.

How can I use the grep feature in this instance to identify this pattern and have it removed.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to remove the entire table (from the opening `<table>` to the ending `</table>`), *if* the string "{{{NOT CONVERTED}}}" appears in the middle of it, then this pattern will match the entire table:

```
(?s)<table.+?>.+?{{{NOT CONVERTED}}}.+?</table>\n
```

(The `(?s)` at the beginning allows `.` to match across line breaks.)

Use "Replace All", replacing with nothing, to delete all of the eligible tables. Undo is your friend if it doesn't do what you need.

Comment: Thanks for your response - I need to specifically identify the table that incl. the line "Not converted' - the html has thousands of other tables that I dont want to remove. The code above will identify every single table and remove it. Is there a way to incoperate the Non-connverted term into your code?

Comment: I've amended my original answer accordingly, hope that does the job.

Comment: Thanks Siegel - I am not  sure if I am doing something wrong but using Find and your code, ticking the Grep option and replacing it with SPACE, still removes all tables in the document. I will update my post to show the code  for the other table to give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Siegel again for your help - I played around with your code and this did the trick:

```html
<table.+?>{{{NOT CONVERTED}}}.+?</table>
```

This successfully identified the tables that had the string not converted in them.

Thanks again !

Comment: Excellent! Delighted to hear you've got a working solution.